# retrofit2 + gson, начать парсинг с конкретной точки

Tags: java, retrofit, gson

Например есть у меня json такого вида

```
{"id":10,"user":"vasya" ... "data":[{что-то},{}...{}]
```

Можно ли как-то исхитриться и начать десериализацию с "data"?
То-есть указать GsonConverterFactory, что его интересует только [{что-то},{}...{}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный вариант который я знаю, это сделать свою реализацию   `JsonDeserializer` и там уже ручками добираться до нужного места.
Подробней [тут](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)