# Нужен простой пример retrofit2 GSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, kotlin

Нужен простой пример использования retrofit2 и gson. Получить данные и вывести куда-нибудь(логи, тост). Можно с pojo или data class, JSON c адреса(http://myjson.com/). Уроки с интернета не помогли...

Такой пример:

```
{
  "firstname":"Пётр",
  "lastname":"Петров"
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522025/retrofit2-gson-начать-парсинг-с-конкретной-точки

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536798/Как-распарсить-json-с-помощью-gson?rq=1

Comment: Мне нужны именно библиотеки, которые я указал в вопросе, они являются востребованными. А ссылки которые вы скинули я уже смотрел ранее.

Comment: может это поможет https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

Comment: @LyaoChin, лучше расскажите что же вам не понятно. Как тоаст вывести, либу подключить или запрос в сеть сделать. Если вы действительно уже смотрели примеры, то ничего нового вам не предложат

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы достаточно много информации можно найти, очень распространённая же библиотека. [Вот пример](http://javaway.info/ispolzovanie-retrofit-2-v-prilozheniyah-android/), [ещё](https://habrahabr.ru/company/rambler-co/blog/275943/)

В наиболее общем случае для начала работы требуется создать:
1) классы модели

```
public class Data {
    public String firstname ;
    public String lastname ;
}
```

2) интерфейс запросов

```
public interface IRest {
    @GET("/your/url")
    Call<Data> getName();
}
```

3) создать объект Retrofit через Retrofit.Builder

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://your.base.url.ru/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

На официальном сайте вроде также достаточно понятное описание, даже вроде сэмпл есть где то

Comment: Так, с эти проблем не возникало. А как получать  данные? Сделать запрос сам (execute, enqueue)?

Comment: IRest m_restService = retrofit.create(IRest.class); 
Response<Data> response = m_restService.getName().execute(); 
Например так. Ну синхронные запросы естественно надо в отдельном потоке вызывать. Если используете асинхронные запросы (enqueue) , то ему нужно передать callback в котором будут переопределены методы onResponse и onFailure

Comment: Спасибо, как проверю, отпишу. Я пока реализовал с fuel и gson.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я завернул решение в AsyncTask(doInBackground) и всё заработало. Правильным ли был мой выбор?

Comment: мне кажется, это уже вопрос вкусовщины (можно любым способом вывести в отдельный поток), ну и в зависимости от решаемой задачи.

Comment: вообще наверное лучше будет сделать асинхронный запрос, раз уж ретрофит позволяет. Для этого надо сначала создать колбэк - например:
Callback<Data> callback = new Callback<Data>() { } в нём вы переопределяете методы onResponse и onFailure (их предложит создать среда) , а потом передаете его при вызове запроса 
m_restService.getName().enqueue(callback); ответ асинхронно придет в onResponse и вы спокойно сможете его обработать. синхронные же запросы нужны, например, если вам нужно сделать последовательные запросы в одном потоке

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь есть прямо пошаговый пример с описанием того, как создать класс из json ответа, как создать экземпляр Retrofit на Kotlin. И пример вывода всего этого на экране http://androidschool.ru/courses/android-retrofit-and-gson/